# to have + verb in the context

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

I wanted to tell my friend that he should do something nice today (it's his birthday):

> You should do something nice, you do not want to have your birthday ending this way.

I know it is wrong but is there a way how to say it still with the "want to have" in the sentence? Or is the "have" here entirely incorrect?

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too sure about use of commas etc. but is this not a comma splice?  I think there is a construction have + inf (w/o "to").  For example, I believe the following is grammatically correct: "I do not like John.  I would have him clean the toilets."  I think that if you were to change "ending" to "end" it would sound better.  That said, "have + participle" is a pretty common construction nowadays as well.

Comment: No, "have your birthday end" would imply that you are causing it to end badly. "Have your birthday ending" is simply saying you are experiencing it.

Comment: @ColinFine I see what you mean.  In the example which I gave, it does imply this.  However, I do not think that it necessarily carries this implication in all instances.  It's a tricky one to decide, as the two are used pretty much interchangeably.